# Can't overwrite location block with other

Tags: nginx

I have two locations:

one

```
location ~ "^/[a-z]{2}[_][A-Z]{2}/customers/[\d]{3,5}" {
proxy_pass http://my-other-site}
```

two

```
location ~ "^/[a-z]{2}[_][A-Z]{2}/customers/[\d]{3,5}/other-folder" {
       alias /user/projects/project/app;}
```

And, accordingly, two requests:

```
http://my-site/en_US/customers/123
```

and

```
http://my-site/en_US/customers/123/other-folder/index.html
```

First request gets in first location block, and it's really what i need,
but second request gets in first location block also,
whereas i need get it in second block. 
What I don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 similar regexp locations, so first defined match wins.

[How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Move longest (second) location up :)